# Mat Menu Trigger on Parent Element from Child

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I would like to position a mat menu popup relative to a parent element.

Angular's documentation says the following about mat menu position:

> By default, the menu will display below (y-axis), after (x-axis), without overlapping its trigger

This is very nice but it's relative to the trigger (matMenuTriggerFor).

I want the menu to open relative to the parent element. Click on button inside div, mat men displays without overlapping it's relative element.

```html
    <gridster-item [item]="w" [class.editing]="w.editing">
      <div class="primary-header widget-settings-bar" color="primary" *ngIf="showSettingsBar == true">
        <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
          <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Delete" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">settings
          </mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
          <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Duplicate" (click)="duplicateDashboardWidget(w)">
            control_point_duplicate</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
          <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Delete" (click)="deleteDashboardWidget(w)">delete
          </mat-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-widget mat-card2">
        <ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]=components[w.component] [ndcDynamicInputs]="w"></ndc-dynamic>
      </div>
    </gridster-item>
```

Here is the widget component I'm talking about.
[Unopened Component (hovering)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPZYE.png)

Here is what happens when you click the matMenuTriggerFor that triggers menu. notice it's overlapping the parent div.
[Triggered from button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzO9e.png)

This is what I want. The menu pops up relative to the parent element. Notice it's not overlapping the div because I put the matMenuTriggerFor on the gridster-item parent.

[Triggered from div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPgMB.png)

Problem is I can't figure out how to make this menu open without matMenuTriggerFor and I don't want the menu to open when clicking on the parent div. I only want the menu to open when clicking the small cogwheel button.

```
<gridster-item [item]="w" [class.editing]="w.editing" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
  <div class="primary-header widget-settings-bar" color="primary" *ngIf="showSettingsBar == true">
    <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
      <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Delete">settings
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
      <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Duplicate" (click)="duplicateDashboardWidget(w)">
        control_point_duplicate</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color">
      <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Delete" (click)="deleteDashboardWidget(w)">delete
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-widget mat-card2">
    <ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]=components[w.component] [ndcDynamicInputs]="w"></ndc-dynamic>
  </div>
</gridster-item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ViewChildren to get a reference to all the matMenuTriggers.

```
@ViewChildren('menuTrigger') matMenuTriggers: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;
```

Then after page is loaded itterate through and disable the `_handleClick`

```
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.matMenuTriggers.changes.subscribe((matMenuTriggers) => {
      matMenuTriggers.toArray().forEach((matMenuTrigger) => matMenuTrigger._handleClick = () => {});
    });
  }
```

You can still call `openMenu` programmatically to open and close the menu from somewhere else. It will open in relationship to the parent div avoiding overlap.

```
        <div class="widget-settings-button contrast-color" (click)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">
          <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Delete">settings
          </mat-icon>
        </div>
```